# Monitor blinks on and off after RAM

Tags: memory, display, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell desktop that had 8 gb of RAM.  I upgraded using the crucial.com scanning tool to determine the right type of memory. At first I left in the two 4GB sticks and put the two 8 gb sticks in the empty slots. That failed. So,I removed the 4GB sticks and put the 8 gb sticks in the slots they were in. In both cases I got a prompt to go to setup or diagnostics,  but the screen kept going off and on at intervals of about 1 second so I couldn'the do anything unless I could read and click during the "on" moments.

In both cases the system recognized the ram, but the machine won'the get past the boot. Any advice?

Comment: Please edit the question title, something like "after RAM upgrade" would be fine.

Comment: Check all of your connections. It sounds like you may have knocked something loose.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the new RAM sticks is bad.  Try just one 8 GB stick in slot one, and if it works OK, then swap for the other to confirm the problem.  It's also possible that both of the new RAM sticks is bad, but unlikely.